# how to create a string using individual characters in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a translator program where every letter of the english alphabet will then display as a made up alphabet.

For instance when I write "a" into the program. The program would display "akh", and If I write "b" it will display "bil". BUT when I write "ab" or "ba" it will only write one of the two. How can I code this so it displays both in the order that I give the English characters

This is the code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim cerilian As String = Nothing
    Dim englishtext As String = Nothing
    englishtext = InputBox("Enter English Text")
    If englishtext.Contains("a") Then
        cerilian = "akh"
    End If
    If englishtext.Contains("b") Then
        cerilian = "bil"
    End If

    TextBox2.Text = cerilian
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: looks like cerilian is getting overwritten by b's case in the case of 'ab'.  Try cerilian = cerilian + " bil".

Comment: that that mean I would have to create a cerilian = cerilian + "whatever" for every single case in the entire alphabet?

Comment: They way you are solving the problem, yes.  26 if cases.  There are other ways of doing it though.  Also, you mentioned order is important. In your example code, "ab" and "ba" will only output "bil".   You will have to think about how to get the characters in order.

Comment: Here is one solution to try: create a map of letters to translations.  a -> akh, b -> bil.  Then loop through the characters in the input one by one, and get the value for that character from the map.

Comment: how do I create a map of letters ;p

Comment: No.  There's a solution in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private map As New Dictionary(Of Char, String)() From _
{ _
    { "a"C, "akh" }, _
    { "b"C, "bil" } _
    ' etc
}

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim englishtext As String = InputBox("Enter English Text")
    TextBox2.Text = String.Join("", _
            englishtext.ToCharArray().Select(Function (x) map(x)))
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like it works, but it has no explanation and does not help what appears to be a very fledgling developer to understand how to think about the problem. Your answer just promotes the "copy and paste code" mentality that does not a good developer make.

Comment: Thank you guys, this is helping me a lot. :D

Comment: @morganlee Do you understand the code? If not, you should ask questions.

Comment: @Gregl I completely understand the code lol don't worry. I know 17 other programming languages. Just to clarify though, this is an array and it's cycling the array/map called "map" and when it hits the correct character, it will display it?

Comment: @GregL - I appreciate your comment, but I don't think the purpose of SO is to provide tutorials. I generally put in more detail depending on the complexity of the question and/or the answer. In this case they're both quite straight forward. I also am happy respond to comments and provide further clarification if needed.